# GCS bucket permission for Project

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I use GCS bucket to upload content. I am distributing a script to my users that helps them download the content in GCS bucket to their local directory.  Each of the users are also GCP project owners.

How do I set permissions in GCS bucket to enable only selected GCP projects to access the contents?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to give access to users in a different project to Cloud Storage bucket you can edit the bucket permissions and can add "Owners, Editors or Viewers" of that project to bucket ACLs e.g. If you want owners of project A to access the bucket with full permissions in project B you can change the permissions of the bucket and add "Project owners- . By doing that all the owners of the project A will have full control on the bucket in project B.

Note: If you change the ACLs of the bucket the changes will apply to new objects uploaded to the bucket. The object already in the bucket will still have the old ACLs.

You can read more about bucket and object ACLs on these links [1]:

[1] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol

Comment: The solution that worked for me was to create an email group alias and whitelist the email Group alias for the GCS bucket access. It helps in 2 things - 1) to manage user addition outside GCS, in the email group  2)keep the whitelist ACL to manageable levels in GCS bucket